# How to assign a text dynamically to a particular textview . (Android)

Tags: android, textview

I have many textviews in my layout.

when a user clicks  a button it should set the text in the edittext to a textview1.

if again the user clicks the text in the edit text should set in textview2 so on textview3    textview4.......

how to go to next textview whenever the user clicks a button

Layout File

```
     ...
    ...
    ...
    ..
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/tvLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
...
...
...
..

and my activity file
```

initialization..

```
    myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tvLayout);
    myTextViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    counter =0;



    for (int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        if (myLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
            myTextViewList.add((TextView) myLayout.getChildAt(i));
```

setting text..

```
          TextView tv = myTextViewList.get(counter);
            tv.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> getChildTextViews(LinearLayout myLayout)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
  {
    View child = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(child instanceof LinearLayout)
      getChildTextViews((LinearLayout) child);
    else if(child instanceof TextView)
      myTextViewList.add((TextView)child);
  }
}



LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lineraLayout);
ArrayList<TextView> myTextViewList = getChildTextViews(myLayout);
int counter = 0;
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
     String txt = et.getText().toString();
     TextView tv = myTextViewList.get(counter);
     tv.setText(txt);
     counter++;
  }
});
```

This is where you get your layout id:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout" >
   //Here is where your TextViews would be declared
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please leave a comment for down voting!

Comment: Are you having all TextViews directly as children of LinearLayout?

Comment: The answer was for the previous question. Anyway I have updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: ya its working well  but i have the textviews in different layout,

Comment: how does that matter now? This code will find all the TextViews.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to down-vote this answer, it's the accepted answer because it solved the problem for @Avinash. If this is not your issue then feel free to up-vote other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Run this for your layout ViewGroup and all TextViews will be in mTextViews.

```
List<TextView> mTextViews = new ArrayList();

void getAllTextViews(ViewGroup v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = v.getChildAt(i);
    if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
        getAllTextViews((ViewGroup)child);
    else if(child instanceof TextView)
        mTextViews.add((TextView)child);
    }
}
```

After that you can set text in your TextViews by common iterator.

Comment: i have only one button. user enters something in edit text  then i validate it if correct it will set to textview1 and the user enters something in the same edittext and clicks the same button i validate and sets the text accordingly ..

Comment: It was my copypaste fault, sorry. See edited answer.